# Backspace malfunctions over SSH when running scheme interpreter

Tags: vim, ssh, scheme

I am trying to SSH into my Ubuntu PC from an iPad to run a scheme interpreter on the terminal.

The backspace works fine for anything else I do over SSH (navigating folders, editing with vim, etc.) but the moment I start a scheme interpreter it starts typing `^H` instead of erasing. I tried guile 1.8, guile 2.0, and racket. They all give me the same problems.

I tried the `#stty -a` and `export TERM=vt100` fixes but they don't change anything. But I'm not familiar with these techniques, so there's a chance I'm doing it wrong.

Here are some information that might be relevant:

My Ubuntu version is 14.04.

I use the free iOS app WebSSH as my SSH client.

The app's terminal settings are set to VT100.

I type on my iPad with a Bluetooth keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `stty erase ^H`. This will make your terminal treat `^H` as backspace.